# How to ensure raster tabulation is in integer using 'tabulate area' tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, tabulate

I'm trying to tabulate raster cells based on its values using the 'Tabulate Area' tool, but the result shows decimal values instead of integer. Is there any way I can ensure the result of the tabulation is integer?

[image: Result of the tabulation is in decimal, not integer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the data that you are trying to tabulate is in geographic coordinates of which the pixel/cell size is in decimal degree. You need to change the projection of the raster data and zonal data to meter projection like UTM, for example, to get a proper area results.

Comment: Reprojected it, but I still got decimals. On QGIS, I used Zonal Raster Statistics, and it gives me the right tabulation for each values, but the thing is, I need to clip my raster multiple times for different polygons. The reason I'm trying to use Tabulate Area in ArcMap is so that I would not have to clip my raster manually, but it never gives me the right output.

Comment: Try to Load the data in a new ArcMap project, and run the tool on the projected data. Make sure that the zones that define the boundary are have also the same projection.

Comment: The Zonal Raster Statistics counts the number of pixels for each class. That is why the value is integer. However, the tabulate area tool gives you the area within each specified zone, and it depends on the projection of the data.